# What do i have to add to this js external page loader to load also java script from the page?

Tags: ajax, jquery, callback

$(window).load(function() {

```
var rel = $('#nav li a').each(function(){
    var page = $(this).attr('rel');

});

$('#nav li a').click(function(){

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('rel')+' #content';
    $('#content').toggle("slide", { direction: "up" }, 700,loadContent);
    $('#load').remove();
    $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
    $('#load').fadeIn('normal');
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('rel').substr(0,$(this).attr('rel').length-5);
    function loadContent() {
        $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent())

    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $('#content').toggle('slide',{direction: 'up'}, 700,hideLoader());

    }

                function hideLoader() {
        $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
    }
    return false;

});
```

});

I have a menu on my web page and wen a button is clicked , an external page ( more exactlly the content div is changed)is loaded in the #content with a slide effect , the code works fine but i have also a foto gallery with java scripts, an the photos dosen't have effects anymore and all that , because i guezz the java script is not loaded!!
please help!!